# protractor by.repeater and visibilityOf only returning first item in collection

Tags: protractor, accordion, angular-ui-bootstrap, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to use protractor's `by.repeater` to find all the elements enumerated in a collection. Being used here are the `(key, value) in expression` enumeration for the ngRepeat directive and [UI Bootstrap accordion directive](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/).

The HTML is:

```
<accordion id="automobile-types" close-others="true">
  <accordion-group heading="{{ autoType }}" 
    ng-repeat="(autoType, details) in automobiles">
    <div>Color of automobile:</div>
      <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="color in details.color">
          {{ color }}
        </li>
      </ul>
   </accordion-group> 
</accordion>
```

Where

```
automobiles = {
 'Car': {'color': 'black', 'name': 'Knight Rider' },
 'Truck': {'color': 'green', 'name': 'Biggins'}
}
```

Using the [protractor example in the angular docs for ngRepeat](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat), here is my protractor code:

```
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
var cars = element.all(by.repeater('(autoType, details) in automobiles')); 

it('should have two automobiles listed', function() {
  var visibleList = EC.visibilityOf(cars);
  browser.wait(visibleList, 5000);
  expect(cars.count()).toEqual(2);
});
```

Returns this failure:

```
Failed: Cannot call method 'bind' of undefined
```

If I remove the `.all`, the test will proceed since it is only finding the first element in the ng-repeat. These tests pass:

```
var car = element(by.repeater('(autoType, details) in automobiles')); 
expect(car.getText()).toEqual('Car');  

var accordion = element(element(by.id('automobile-types')));
expect(accordion.getText()).toEqual('Car\nTruck');
```

I tried to solve this by using ng-repeat-start and ng-repeat-end, but that didn't solve it, it continued to only return the first element in the collection.

Any advice on how to return the block of html for each automobile would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should call the `element.all()` inside the `it()`. And there is a missing comma at the end of the line where you define the `cars`. Fixed version:

```
it('should have two automobiles listed', function() {
    var cars = element.all(by.repeater('(autoType, details) in automobiles'));
    expect(cars.count()).toEqual(2);
});
```

If this is still not working, try using [`by.exactRepeater()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ProtractorBy.prototype.exactRepeater):

```
var cars = element.all(by.exactRepeater('(autoType, details) in automobiles'));
```

Or, switch to alternative location technique:

```
var cars = $$('[ng-repeat="(autoType, details) in automobiles"]');
```

Here, `$$` is a shortcut for `element.all(by.css())`.

Comment: Thanks alecxe for the help and for the syntax suggestions.  I implemented your suggestion about using `$$`, I had not thought of that, but I still came up with the same failure. The problem I am encountering is that the element selector will not return `.all` of the list. It is only returning the first item in the repeat collection, while still rendering each item in the HTML. I was thinking maybe it was a conflict with bootstrap's accordion derivative or the `key,pair` syntax for the ngRepeat, but I couldn't find information about either of those two things.

Comment: @JessG yeah, good point, I think I saw this error multiple times before and, I suspect, it is kind of a generic error. Let's debug it. Could you post your config, the complete test and the traceback? Thanks, we'll solve it.

Comment: @JessG Maybe try to open ```<accordion>``` before get all the element inside. ```$('#automobile-types').click(); browser.waitForAngular();``` then ```$$('[ng-repeat="(autoType, details) in automobiles"]');``` --- I got exactly same error output back there, I remember I did some sort of timming condition like this, to make sure Protractor ```element.all()``` does not fired before JS has done all the undergoing tasks.

Comment: @alecxe While I was assembling the complete test,config and traceback to share with you...I think I may have come across the answer.  It turns out I left out a few lines of code here that I didn't think were important. I updated my code above and looks like the failure about 'bind' was in response to the `Expected Condition visibiltyOf`.  I think the `visibiltyOf` method only takes a single element and I was passing it a list of elements. Does that seem accurate @alecxe?

Comment: @JessG definitely, my bad not noticing it. Good finding!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the failure about `Cannot call method 'bind' of undefined` was in response to the `Expected Condition visibiltyOf` and not about the `by.repeater` like originally assumed.

Looks like `visibiltyOf` method only takes a **single** element while a list of elements was being passed. These tests passed now:

```
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
var cars = element.all(by.repeater('(autoType, details) in automobiles')); 
var carTypes = element(by.id('automobile-types));

it('should have two automobiles listed', function() {
  var visibleList = EC.visibilityOf(carTypes);
  browser.wait(visibleList, 5000);
  expect(cars.count()).toEqual(2);
});
```